# How to embedded a URL parameter within an href URL?

Tags: html, ios

I am trying to encode HTML with an 'href' URL that contains a URL parameter:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=....">
  Download Some File
</a>
```

[This is related to an Apple Enterprise account - the HTML link instructs iOS to download the file.]

It appears that the '&' character results in having what follows interpreted as a second parameter.

Is there any way to encode or escape that second '&' character? Or is it possible to re-write the href to not use quotes, and use the quotes for the parameter following "url="?

Comment: Have you tried HTML Encoding the query string?

Comment: @GeorgeJohnston -  Well, due to the way google drive works, it takes several minutes for me to construct each test. If you mean changing the second '&' into a '&amp;', yes I did. Unfortunately when it fails, nothing happens on the iOS device - there is no way to know WHY it failed, just that it has. I assume that I'm not the first person who has hit this embed URL within a URL, and that the solution is "commonly known", but googling for 1/2 has not lead me to any answers. HTML encoding is way out of my zone too.

Comment: `itms` are a damn pain the backside! I feel your pain about the lack of something happening too! Have you tried URL encoding the special characters in the `url=` bit? Also wouldn't you also need to HTML encode the first `&` too? (I'm not big on HTML!)

Comment: @Rich Everytime I change the html text (which Google won't let me edit), I have to remove the old file, upload the new file, change its permissions, get the id, then re-write the link and email it to my iPad to test with. Nothing happens. Then I try again. Thus my hope someone has an answer for me here!

Comment: @DavidH you can speed up your testing by not worrying about the ID for the moment, just make one up. If the ID is incorrect (and I presume the link goes no where then?) you'll get a error message (something about being unable to connect to the host). The problem is with the format of the link (as you've said), which means no error is shown (though thinking about it now I do remember seeing some sort of error in the console). Least you can play around with the encoding till you get an error message.

Comment: Is there no way you can knock up a quick web server on your machine and host a page with a link with dummy URL parameters for quicker testing?

Comment: @Rich per your suggestion, URL encoding the whole URL did the trick. Only doing a few characters did not. I used the URL encoder from the link in the answer to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to URL encode the "url=" parameter - then it took. I had tried a few characters, but when I used the URL Encode feature on the [HTML URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) (see form half way down the page), that worked. I guess this should have been obvious on rethinking the problem.